# What to say in-order to stop a long boring conversation?

Tags: conversation

Suppose two friends got into an argument which turned out to be an unending debate. And one of them wanted to end it. What are the different ways to express this?

Comment: "Let's agree to disagree"

Comment: Would you look at the time...  Gotta go. See ya.  <walk away>

Comment: "This is going nowhere. Can we just drop it?"

Comment: "Sorry, but I gotta go pee really bad."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of straight-forward phrases to simply end your conversation, you might consider: -

> "Let's sleep on it."
>
> "Perhaps we should agree to disagree."

If you feel like these are a bit 'blunt', there are some good ideas on how to end a conversation [here](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/business-career/public-speaking/how-to-end-a-conversation?page=1) (and this is just another class of conversation after all).

I like the first strategy: -

> The first strategy, the positive comment, is the most frequently used
>   conversation ending strategy. It is exactly what it sounds like: a
>   positive comment and it’s almost a direct negation that your
>   conversation partner is boring or annoying.  Include the name of the
>   person in your closing to make it just a little more personal.
>
> For example, at the end of my conversation with Steve, I could have
>   said, “Hey Steve, I’m glad we talked, you gave me some interesting
>   ideas to think about.”

So in this instance you might say.

"Hey Steve it's been great discussing this, I have really enjoyed it. Call me tomorrow, ok?"

"Hey Sarah I've really enjoyed our discussion, but I've got to head home now, I'll call you soon!"

The key is to end on a positive comment with this technique.

Comment: He didn't say he wanted a positive resolution. "You're stubborn as a mule and not nearly as smart" would end the debate pretty quickly.

Comment: I didn't say, he said he wanted a positive resolution...